# Why hot towel not loading my Javascript files

Tags: single-page-application, hottowel

I installed hottowel. Modified **Shell.html** as below

```
<section id="content" >
     <!--ko compose: {view: 'master'} --><!--/ko-->
</section>
```

In **master.html** file i call another html file called **search.html**

```
<section >
        <div id="SearchDetails">
            <section>
                 <!--ko compose: {view: 'search'} --><!--/ko-->
            </section>

        </div>
```

It loads search.html fine. But it is not calling my restservice which i have written **search.js** as below

```
define(['services/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {
var productVersionData = ko.observableArray();
var initialized = false;
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    productVersionData: productVersionData

};
return vm;

function activate() {
    alert(" i am hit");
    if (initialized) { return; }
    initialized = true;
    return refresh();
}

function refresh() {
    return dataservice.getProductVersionPartials(productVersionData);
}

});
```

In my **shell.js** i am calling all view models like below

```
define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
function (system, router, logger) {
    var shell = {
        activate: activate,
        router: router
    };

    return shell;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        return boot();
    }

    function boot() {
        router.mapNav('master');
        router.mapNav('search');
        log('Hot Towel SPA Loaded!', null, true);
        return router.activate('master');
    }

    function log(msg, data, showToast) {
        logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(shell), showToast);
    }

});
```

I put debugger statement, console.log statements inside **search.js** but it is not somehow loading search.js. That is why it is not calling my service defined in dataservice.
What could be issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the change you made in the **shell.html** file within the content section. Make the following change and your 404 should go away:

```
<section id="content" class="main container-fluid">
    <!--ko compose: {model: 'viewmodels/master', activate: true} -->
    <!--/ko-->
</section>
```

I'm not familiar with the **config.js** pattern you're using, but I would think you'd want to go back to the using the router for dynamically setting the `model` parameter in **shell.html** and configure the activated route in the **shell.js** `boot` function that comes with the Hot Towel template.

Comment: i have changed my question. Now i dont use config.js but use router.mapNav. But somehow it is not loading search.js file. Please see more details in my question. Sorry about it.

Comment: I am sorry but honestly i solved the issue even before you had answered. Many thanks for your efforts so +1 for you